# Multiple If condition are not working

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Below is an array which is having two key-value pair:

```
Array ([web_tokens] => ft2TxdXhon8,fYTsgCoCrBY
       [phone_tokens] => c-hqzdEjs2M,dWahJ8MOfXY, dkYoMgoPNN8)
```

Now the problem is if I want to fetch them separately within a `if statement` , only the first `if statement` is working.

```
if(!empty($tokens['web_tokens'])) {
     $tokens = explode(',',$tokens['web_tokens']);
     print_r($tokens);
}

if(!empty($tokens['phone_tokens'])) {
     $tokens = explode(',',$tokens['phone_tokens']);
     print_r($tokens);
}
```

Here only the `web_tokens` are displaying but not the `phone_tokens`. Means the second if condition is not working even if the array has `phone_tokens` value.

Also when I comment the first `If statement` the second statement works fine.

Comment: Because you have updated `$tokens` in first `if`.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank You.

Comment: Variable confusion, is what I call it...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yep :)

Comment: Wait tell you mix casing on a variable, then you will get really confused because they are case sensitive.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - that's why I love linux so much - you have to learn the hard way about making sure the case is exactly the same.

Comment: My first brush with linux was learning how to build Apache on Knopix, fun times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overriding the values in the first if and so the second if will fail...

```
if(!empty($tokens['web_tokens'])) {
     $tokensWeb = explode(',',$tokens['web_tokens']);
     print_r($tokensWeb);
}

if(!empty($tokens['phone_tokens'])) {
     $tokensPhone = explode(',',$tokens['phone_tokens']);
     print_r($tokensPhone);
}
```

Using generic names can cause all sorts of problems later, try and use names which identify the content more uniquely.

Comment: Choose the right name for variable is really an art. $tokensWeb vs $webTokens. Nice

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen I'm sure someone will find a flaw in anything you try, reason why I chose the above was that they are both part of $tokens, so it groups them logically (in my head) with it.  Although from the code fragment, you could just `print_r()` them directly and avoid the temporary variable.

Comment: @NigelRen, totally agree.